# Styling two views using the same template file?

Tags: views, 6

I have two views that are pretty similar so I want them to use the same template file. However, in views I can only select templates that have a name unique to that view meaning two views can't use the same template. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your views are same or similar then manage both of views as one using multiple views displays. For each display settings and configuration can be overridden. Template can be shared among displays of a single view.

The other a little bit bad way, can be to create a single template file and then include that template to your views templates.

Comment: I never though of adding another display. It works for what I want. thanks