# How to consistently style the titles of Views in my Panels sidebar?

Tags: 7, views, theming, panels

My Panels website has a sidebar and I put several Views in there as Panes. Every View has a title and I would like to wrap this title in a `h3` header. Until now, I manually overrode the Pane's title with **%title** and chose the `h3` tag in the Pane's settings. This works fine, but sometimes I forget to make the adjustments and then things look ugly for a while. It is also possible that one day I prefer to use `h2` instead and then I will be facing dozens of Panes to adapt.

Therefore, I would like to know whether there is an easier and more efficient way to achieve what I want. After reading [Drupal 7 Views: Use one views.tpl.php file for multiple views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53958/drupal-7-views-use-one-views-tpl-php-file-for-multiple-views), I thought about using a View template, but I cannot just tag the Views that will turn up in the sidebar, because some Views have multiple blocks and only one of them will be put in the sidebar.

Do you have any suggestions that might make life easier for me (or at least the website developing side)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to target it with css.

```
.pane-region-class .pane-title h2,
.pane-region-class .pane-title h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  etc.
}
```

I think you can add classes to panel regions. And do the above without `h2` / `h3` to style the general title.